# grep recursive exclusive search

Tags: debian, grep

I have text I want to recursively search in `mydir/`. I would normally type `grep -r "text to find" mydir/"` but what would I type if I wanted to search all the files except a specific one?

For example, I do not want to search the file "myfile.txt" but it is contained in the directory.

What would I type?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can achieve this by `--exclude` and `--exclude-dir` options of grep

For example:

```
grep -r --exclude-dir='<dirs_to_exclude>' PATTERN data
```

or

```
grep -r --exclude='<pattern_of_file>' PATTERN data
```

Comment: You can also look for [ack](http://betterthangrep.com/) for code searching.